# How to store HDCP encryption key on a PC?

Tags: gpu, h.264, hdmi, hdcp

I am receiving **HDCP encrypted H264** content over **TCP/IP** to PC from an encoder. I need to decrypt and pass the buffer to GPU for decoding and **HDMI(HDCP encrypted)** output. I am planning to do the complete processing inside **TEE**. Where can I store **HDCP encryption key**?